# pip list shows module but error shows module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to work with this implementation of the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker Algorithm](https://github.com/fhirschmann/rdp). I have created a virtual environment, installed the package and checked with `pip list`. This shows that the package and numpy have been installed.

I checked `sys.prefix` and it is pointing to the correct `venv`.

When I try `from rdp import rdp` I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdp'

Looking in the Finder, I can see rdp and numpy in site-packages.

Despite checking many of the similar questions here, nothing seems to quite solve my problem.

Using python 3.8 on MacOS 11.6.5

What can I do?

Comment: did you activate the venv before installing and/or running? and can you `import rdp` from the REPL?

Comment: Yes, I did activate the venv. I did not initally try from the REPL. I just did that now, and there is no error. Not sure what that means. Should I edit the original question?